# Batch-making PDFs with different excel rows

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am not sure if this is doable in excel, but since it has a lot of powerful features I am thinking there might be a way.
I have a Sheet of excel that has multiple rows of data.
I have sheet 2 that is basically a printable version of this data, however it only corresponds to 1 row of data.
Is there a way for me to mass-save PDF's of Sheet 2 but with each different row?
for example, A2, B2, C2, D2 contain certain data that is spread across different parts of Sheet 2. I want to populate them and save as PDF, then I want A3,B3,C3 & D3 to re-populate the fields & overwrite the previou sones and save a PDF with a new name (or just sequential).
Is this possible or not?
I have a little experience with VBA in Access and some experience with Swift & other programming languages so I know some basics.

Comment: This is totally doable, you need to iterate through the rows on sheet 1 to populate sheet 2 and export a PDF on each iteration. Can you please post the code that you have so far and identify any lines that are throwing errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution will depend on how your data is staged, but as an example consider the following data.

[image]

On Sheet 2 set the print area to the portion that you want the PDF to include.

Then this loop would create a PDF for each ID that is found in Column A on Sheet 1:

```
Private Sub exportToPDFLoop()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
    End With

    For Each c In rng

        'Skip Row 1 (headers)
        If c.Row > 1 Then

            With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

                .Range("B1").Value = c.Value

                .Calculate

                .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
                    ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testfilename_" & CStr(c.Value) & ".pdf", Quality:= _
                    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=True

            End With

        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how would I go about renaming the PDF as "Range"B1".value (say each PDF will be the ID on your example?

Comment: Edited my solution to skip row 1, since that probably contains headers.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your follow up question. In my solution above, the PDF is already being renamed using the ID by this line: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\testfilename_" & CStr(c.Value) & ".pdf"`. `CStr(c.Value)` is the Id that is going in B2 on each iteration. You can modify that file name concatenation as needed.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I dont know why i thought C was a counter not the actual value. That was my bad.

Comment: As of now I'm modifying the entire worksheet using VLOOKUP and itearting over one value. But just as a question, if I would want the code to change more than one cell would I need a new rng array range and a new c counter (say rng2 and c2) and another for loop?

Comment: I guess that depends on how your data is staged. I would use offsets before doing an additional loop. `c` is the current cell in the looped range `A:A`, so for example c.value is going into B2, but you could could also grab `c.offset(0,1).value` and put it somewhere else - for example `.Range("B2").Value = c.offset(0,1).value`. In my proposed solution `.Range("B1").Value = c.Value` is just a place holder for whatever copy/transformation process(es) you want to do.